# Find all functions generated by macros

Tags: c, macros

I am trying to generate various functions using macros in C. Is there any way for me to see all the functions generated during compilation?

Comment: Use compiler options to only pre-process the file?

Comment: There should be a way to get your compiler to output the code generated after macro processing, do a diff against your original source to see what was generated.

Comment: Yes, just run your source through the preprocessor, e.g. `gcc -E ...`

Comment: How to do it depends on the development environment.  Let us know what you're using.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using gcc, the option -save-temps saves the intermediate steps of compilation (preprocessed files and assembly code) while generating binary.

You can see a brief description [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `nm` on the object file to get the name of public (non `static`) functions.

You could pass the `-v` option to the `cc1` to get the the name of compiled functions.

You could also extend your recent GCC compiler using [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/)

And of course, you could get the preprocessed form, as other answers suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can use -E option of the gcc compiler to view the preprocessed file.

```
gcc -E main.c > main.i
```

Comment: Remove the header file inclusion statements (#include) to not get a clustered output. The file will not compile, just stops after preprocessing, so you will not get errors.

Comment: Thanks. Can I do some thing like this g++ -o testMacro -E testMacro.cpp. Find out the macros while generating binary